# Хостинг из компа

Tags: django, hosting, веб-сайт

Мне надо сделать из компа своего старого сделать хостинг для сайта на Джанго (бд на постгрес). Статический ip есть, хотел с open server, начал читать, везде про то, что Джанго сам разворачивает на localhoste, а мне надо, чтобы он просто в интернете лежал, как это сделать?

P.S. Это мой первый сайт, поэтому вообще нет ни опыта, ни знаний в этих всех хостингах и так далее)

Comment: Непонятно в чём конкретная проблема у вас, в документации Django есть целый раздел про способы деплоя https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/

Answer (score 0):

Ну по идее localhost это ваш локальный ip адрес. А значит вам надо просто в настройках роутера перенаправить веб порт (80 и 443) на ваш локальный внутри сети ip адрес. Таким образом подключаясь к ip вашего роутера вы будете автоматически перенаправляться на localhost вашего компьютера. **Если кратко: по сути localhost это просто ваш локальный ip, и вам надо, что бы роутер перенаправлял запросы со своего ip на ваш компьютер**

Comment: ну вот вопрос в том, как мне надо сделать это? как привязать к этому домен? как сделать его доступным всегда? как привязать к нему ssl

Comment: @ЗюбинВладислав а вот эти вопросы не имеют никакого отношения ни к Django, ни к компу, и информации в интернете об этом навалом

Comment: @ЗюбинВладислав Домен настраивается отдельно. Есть много бесплатных ДНС серверов, которые будут перенаправлять запросы на ваш ip.